# efficient copying of arrays in Java

Tags: java, object, copy

In Java, given a list `xs` can we obtain the list `ys` such that the nth element of `ys` is given a new value. `xs` is not modified. Can this be done without having to copy all of `xs`, referring to the copy as `ys` then modifying `ys`?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> xs = new ArrayList<Integer>(100);

        xs.add(10);
        System.out.println(xs.get(0)); // prints 10

        destructiveCall(xs);
        System.out.println(xs.get(0)); // prints 5

        List<Integer> ys = nonDestructiveUpdate(xs);
        System.out.println(xs.get(0)); // prints 5 (the value has not changed)
        System.out.println(ys.get(0)); // prints 20 (the value set in the nonDestructiveUpdate)

    }

    private static void destructiveCall(List<Integer> xs) {
        xs.set(0, 5);
    }

    private static List<Integer> nonDestructiveUpdate(List<Integer> xs) {
        List<Integer> ys = new ArrayList<Integer>(xs);
        // is there a way of doing this without copying the whole list?
        ys.set(0, 20);
        return ys;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want a deep-copy of the array and all its elements then you have to touch every element at least once - there is no way around it to my knowledge.

Comment: you'll need some wrapper around plain arrays for this.

Comment: Do you want changes in xs to show up in ys?  Or do you want the isolation to go both ways?

Comment: @Thomas ideally both ways, but one way would probably work if it was much easier / cheaper to implement...

Comment: If you want two-way isolation, you need two copies.  For one-way, you can make a wrapper class, but it may end up being less time efficient(but still more space efficient) than having two copies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own class which holds "base list", in your case `xs` and another virtual list - `ys`, where you track the changes. You can create methods and iterator for your `ys` virtual list, so it can appear as real list, even it is not.

But in standard libraries o Java funcionality I do not know about something like this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. If you want to update ys without updating xs, then they have separate states. If you're worried about the list elements being cloned, they won't be. But you probably do want the references to be copied, so that you can manipulate them non-destructively.

If you're looking for ys to keep track of only the changes, then @libik has a good suggestion, but it'll get tricky very quickly depending on what operations you need to support (if it's just updates, it won't be too hard, but inserts/deletes will be harder).